# Sequelize query. Where condition using calculated values

Tags: sequelize.js

This is how it happens in a usual mySQL request.

> SELECT * from table WHERE (sec - duration) < 10

But I didn’t find in the documentation for sequelize how to do it

Can anyone tell me how to do this in where object in sequelize query??? PLease ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more suitable solution !!!

```html
Table.findAll({
  where: {
    sec:{
      [Op.lt]: sequelize.literal(duration + 10)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`sec - duration < 10` is equivalent to `sec < 10 + duration`, or `sec < SUM(10, duration)`. We can just use the SQL `SUM` function with `sequelize.fn`:

```js
Table.findAll({
  where: {
    sec:{
      [Op.lt]: sequelize.fn('sum', 10, sequelize.col('duration'))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is no working - i get sql syntax error(((

Comment: Try it your self and you will see))) i alrady shut down the server (( but sequelize told me - sql syntax error... any way i found another way with literal and this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: But in any case, thank you so much for the mitematic solution.